# Unable to use minimatch with intercept in Cypress 6.2.1

Tags: cypress

I have an issue with cy.intercept that I can't seem to figure out how to solve, in our project we used to use route, but now trying to start using intercept. So, our rotes used to be defined like this:

```
'upload: {route: `api/cases/import-data/**`, alias:'upload'}
```

So we used minimatch's `**` to mach anything after the `import-data/`, and that is currently not working with intercept.

So I'm trying to use RegExp instead now, so my question is pretty simple, what should I replace `**` with in a RegExp? Nothing seems to be working and I'm getting a timeout error.

My function:

```
function listener({ route, method = 'POST', onRes = () => { }, alias = 'listener' }) {
  const url = new RegExp(`${Cypress.config().beUrl}${route}`);

  cy.intercept(
    method,
    url,
    (req) => {
      req.reply(res => {
        onRes(res);
      });
    }
  ).as(alias);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex you don't need anything to replace minimatch '**'. `"api/cases/import-data/**"` can translate to `/api\/cases\/import-data/`.

But note the escaped forward slashes, which I think is the missing ingredient in

```
const url = new RegExp(`${Cypress.config().beUrl}${route}`)
```

The strings you use to build the regex don't contain the backslash escape for path delimiters.

This might work

```
const escapedBaseUrl = Cypress.config().beUrl.replace('/', '\/');
const escapedRoute = route.replace('/', '\/');
const url = new RegExp(`${escapedBaseUrl}${escapedRoute}`);
```

but sooner or later you can run into other characters that need escaping, so you can use a package like [regex-escape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex-escape),

```
const RegexEscape = require("regex-escape");
...
const url = new RegExp(RegexEscape(`${Cypress.config().beUrl}${route}`));
```

Comment: So, I finally figured out what the issue was, basically, instead of `**` I needed to use `\w+` like this: `api\/cases\/import-data\/\\w+$` and passing a url and method as an object properties like: this `cy.intercept({ url, method, matchUrlAgainstPath: false}`, also `replace` would not replace double slashes such as `http://`, so used `replaceAll` instead. Thank you for your answer though, helped me a bit!